# Cannot use calculated offset in BigQuery's DATE_ADD function

Tags: google-bigquery, tableau-api, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to create a custom query in Tableau to use on Google's BigQuery. The goal is to have an offset parameter in Tableau that changes the offsets used in a date based WHERE clause.

In Tableau it would look like this:

```
  SELECT
DATE_ADD(UTC_USEC_TO_MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()),<Parameters.Offset>-1,"MONTH") as month_index,
COUNT(DISTINCT user_id, 1000000) as distinct_count
  FROM
[Orders]
  WHERE
order_date >= DATE_ADD(UTC_USEC_TO_MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()),<Parameters.Offset>-12,"MONTH")
  AND
order_date < DATE_ADD(UTC_USEC_TO_MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()),<Parameters.Offset>-1,"MONTH")
```

However, BigQuery always returns an error:

```
Error: DATE_ADD 2nd argument must have INT32 type.
```

When I try the same query in the BigQuery editor using simple arithmetic it fails with the same error.

```
SELECT
DATE_ADD(UTC_USEC_TO_MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()),5-3,"MONTH") as month_index,
  FROM [Orders]
```

Any workaround for this? My only option so far is to make multiple offsets in Tableau, it seems.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: It's not related to the missing time zone functionality. We're at 2 hours before UTC during summer, and just 1 during winter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I acknowledge that this is a hole in functionality of DATE_ADD. It can be fixed, but it will take some time until fix is rolled into production.

Comment: Thanks Mosha. Can we follow on this somewhere?

Comment: Please enter this issue at https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/ and I will accept it there.

Comment: Okay, entered as issue 254: https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=254

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible workaround.  It seems to work if the first argument to DATE_ADD is a string.  Then you can truncate the result to a month boundary and convert it from a timestamp to a string.

```
SELECT
FORMAT_UTC_USEC(UTC_USEC_TO_MONTH(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(),5-3,"MONTH"))) as month_index;
```